Why isn't the Liar's Paradox just accepted to be complete nonsense?
I can understand that some self-referential sentences can be sensible and have truth/false values (e.g. "This sentence is written in English." is true, "This sentence has 1,000 words." is false). However, the sentence "This sentence is false." has no meaning. Its as nonsensical as "This sentence is true". What does it mean for this sentence to be true? How would you even prove/disprove this sentence is true? If "This sentence is true." is nonsensical, why can't "This sentence is false." be nonsensical too?
Thanks.
Please explain in simple layman English.

Things in the world are not always what they seem since there're uncertainties, as Kant's transcendental thesis implicitly attributes nonsense to the inherent or post hoc lack of its intuition at current level. Perhaps it makes sense to be a lamp passed from the ancient sages to shed the sensical light to the the extremely deep and important Godel sentence 'this sentence is unprovable', not unlike Aristotle's nonsense of unmoved mover...

Because it is formed like many other sentences taken to have meanings and there is no non-controversial semantic theory that would make them meaningful but not it. By the way, having a meaning does not require having a truth value. All meaningful imperative and interrogative sentences, and some declarative ones, are not truth-apt either. But, for what it is worth, some semantic theories do assign even a truth value to the Liar, see IEP. So "just accepting" is not an option, even theories that do declare the Liar 'meaningless' offer long elaborations.

That's the point of the paradox, actually.

"Much madness is divinest sense, much sense, the starkest madness." - Emily Dickinson

Nonsense is much less intelligible, even ghsorlpzs is at the very least not a word and a rhetorical device befitting a time and place. You saying the Liar is complete nonsense would make you come off as a feeble decreer of English is all. Others play with it as they please. If you seek to really restrict it to nonsense, you’ll have to try much harder. This isn’t hostile, I’m just trying to get a point across.

I don't understand what you're getting at with this question. You seem to be aware that "this statement is false" can't be assigned a truth value because of being self-referential. You then claim that being self-referential implies being nonsense, but this requires defining "nonsense" first. "Nonsense" as in "not very useful in everyday life"? Yes. "Nonsense" in the same way as "colorless green ideas..." is nonsense? Not necessarily, because that one isn't self-referential and is problematic for different reasons.

Language is mostly contextual and the apparent paradox in this case can be solved almost trivially by reducing it to a contradiction; statements like "a is b" says fundamentally "it is true that "a is b"" and true means conforming to the reality of the domain of the sentence. Thus the claim is of form 'this sentence is true AND this sentence is false', which is a contradiction and therefore is indeed meaningless in the sense of telling some truth about the reality.

Careful, keep asking questions like this and you may end up being a philosopher.

If the Liar strikes you as too easy, try Moore's paradox. It is the conjunction of two propositions, each of which is perfectly sensible in isolation, but they become absurd when combined.

What you describe is a version of the "Liar paradox" and it cannot be interpreted in the same exact way. In the "Liar paradox" a person says "I am lying". Anyway, both are self-contradictory statements and as such there are considered real paradoxes (by definition). The "Liar paradox" is a classic philosopical paradox and it is not a nonsense (as a lot of other "pseudo" paradoxes).

You ask:

Why isn't the Liar's Paradox just accepted to be complete nonsense?

You want an answer in "plain English." The easy explanation is that "complete nonsense" intuitively would be a construction like "Fliba jibba jobby ho funkle" where there is no meaning (as "sense" is a synonym for "meaning"). Clearly, "This sentence is false" is unlike a completely nonsensical sentence composed of random sounds because it is both understandable, and one can have intelligent discourse with and about it.
All of the words have meaning, and the meaning of the entire sentence at first glance is meaningful, and any sentence with those properties isn't nonsensical. Even "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously" isn't nonsensical, because by the Principle of Compositionality, its words and some of its phrases have meaning. Completely nonsensical statements have to be statements that contain no meaning by part or whole and that doesn't describe the Liar's Paradox at all.
In fact, the sentence is so meaningful, that it meets the definition of a paradox which means that not only does one find it meaningful, but it's surprising that's there's a logical problem with the sentence at all! Paradoxes are logical claims like fallacies are logical arguments: they are very persuasive and misleading on the surface, and it is only a careful analysis that reveals they are problematic.

Let me know if that is "layman" enough for you. I can break down some of the technical vocabulary if need be.

I get the "colorless green ideas..." is gramatically well-formed, but it is semantically nosensical based on what was said in Wikipedia page. Couldn't this also apply to "This sentence is true" and "This sentence is false"?

@HelpMePlease the semantics are fine - it's the actual logic that's interesting. "This sentence is true" is not by definition nonsense - a sentence like this one that is a statement of fact in most cases is either true or false - 'some other sentence is true' can be expected to generally either be true or false, and it's almost identical to your examples except it isn't self-referencial.

@aantia how would you respond to this : https://steve-patterson.com/resolving-the-liars-paradox/
Only case where Liar's paradox makes sense is if you know someone who has told lies everytime they spoke (100% of speech = lies), and their last statement before death is "Everything I said while alive was a lie." Determining the truth value of their last sentence results in Liars paradox.
However, I dont get how you can just say "this sentence is false". it makes no gramatical sense. You might as well say "this elephant is false" or "this color is false".

@HelpMePlease Sentences which are statements of fact are a thing that is normally true or false. Saying 'sentence X is false' is grammatically fine. There are only some special cases where it results in a paradox. My response to Patterson would be that all he's done is play around with trivial semantics, waffle a bit, and then decree that semantics are all that exist - he refuses to examine the actual issue of paradoxes in self-referential logic.

@HelpMePlease Liar's paradox (its logic, to be precise) can be formalized and is actually used in mathematics to prove, for example, undecidability of the Halting Problem. Difficulties of applying this paradox to real people are irrelevant.

We use the predicates "... is true" and "... is false" in everyday speech and in scientific speech to make comments about propositions. Those comments are themselves also intended as propositions.
Problems arise when those predicates are applied to the sentences themselves. That is, in particular when somebody utters "This sentence is false". Even though the apostle Paul in Titus 1:12,13 writes

One among themselves, even a prophet of their own, said, “The Cretans are always liars, evil beasts, slothful gluttons." This witness is true. Therefore rebuke them sharply, that they may be sound in the faith.

showing that he perhaps didn't have a sharp eye for logical finesse, most people find it paradoxical since the Liar's sentence would be true if and only if false.
If you then ask what makes that sentence into a pathological edge case, some will say that this is because of the involved self-reference (or rather the combination of self-reference with semantic notions, as here "is true" and "is false"). In many other semantic paradoxes, such as Berry's paradox, that use semantic terms like "name", "definition" or "description", self-reference also seems to be the major culprit.
But if self-reference is the major culprit here, then the mirror sentence "This sentence is true" also needs to be looked at with suspicion. It's definitely possible to then argue that, since the Liar sentence and the Truth-Teller sentence have exactly the same form (the same schema), then if one is a pathological edge case, without a clear sense, then the other may also be pathological "nonsense".
On the other hand, it's also possible to argue: It's only because we assign a certain sense or meaning to the Liar sentence that we are able to derive a self-contradiction. Argued like that, the Liar is not simple "nonsense", but just a self-contradiction, while the Truth-Teller may makes sense, but doesn't seem to say anything substantial. (There are ways to formalize this in a formal system, however, and then the equivalent of the Truth-Teller could be vacously true. For more technical details see Self-Reference and Paradox) You could argue that "not saying anything substantial" is also a form of "nonsense", but in this whole line of argument, a counter-argument would be: Well, at least it shows a way of using the predicate "is true" in a vacously true sentence.
What is "nonsense" or not really depends, in the end, on which use you want to make of language.
Twas bryllyg, and þe slythy toves
Did gyre and gymble in þe wabe

Did they really or not? In my imagination they truly did. --- In fact, I now imagine that the "slythy toves" may be the sly logicians (and us) who are "gyring and gymbling" in the "wabe" of this question (it definitely has a "long way be fore it and a long way be hind it" as Humpty Dumpty explained). And "bryllyg" suggests the heat wave that sometimes arises in these discussions and causes us to "gymble" like desperate gimlets trying to bore holes in our thoughts.

Is there a difference in meaning between "This sentence is true", and "This proposition is true"? I wonder if that's what OP is getting at, because for me the second sounds more meaningful than the first.

@DanGetz It's definitely possible to posit/assume/make a difference between those two, but generally people make no difference between them  in the context of this kind of discussion. (In German "Satz" which is often used, means both sentence and proposition.) If you make a distinction, then you would probably only use "is true" for propositions and you would see sentences as the signs that somehow express or carry propositions. It would then not make sense to say that any "sentence" is true (otherwise you have to wonder if "true" has two meanings - which would become very strange!)

@DanGetz - Your question has a lot more too it though! You can wonder: Can we define the terms "is true"/"is false" and "proposition" indepedently from each other? I don't think we can! A "proposition" (or call it however you like) is something that can be "true" or "false". But "true" or "false" is something that can only be said of "propositions". The concept of "true"/"false" belongs to our concept of "proposition" (and vice-versa). Wittgenstein has some interesting comments about this in Philosophical Investigations 136.

(Link PI 136: https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54889e73e4b0a2c1f9891289/t/564b61a4e4b04eca59c4d232/1447780772744/Ludwig.Wittgenstein.-.Philosophical.Investigations.pdf)

@mudskipper While 'Satz' is often used to mean a proposition, particularly in mathematics outside of logic, the more specific term for that is 'Aussage'.

Thanks, yes - I mainly wanted to highlight the fact that "Satz" is ambiguous - it's also used just to refer to the grammatical unit of a "sentence" (see for instance the definition in Duden "Was ist ein Satz?"). Many philosophical texts seem a bit sloppy. In English we can also distinguish for instance "utterance" (spoken), "sentence" (written or spoken), "proposition" (what is said by a sentence stating a fact), "statement", "assertion" ...

The issue with such statements as The Liar, is that their self-reference is entirely to their own semantic truth value.
The semantic "truth" of a statement arises when the mind compares the claim make by that statement to the "state of the world".
The statement P: "Paris is the capital of France" is true while Paris remains the capital of France.
But, to know the truth value of P, we have to compare P to the real world, and P must make some verifiable claim in order to determine its truth value.
If a statement just refers to its own truth value, it skips over the ONLY means by which its own truth value can be determined -- it provides NO way to determine its semantic truth value.
This is known as un-grounded self-reference, and Joshua Matthews at the University of Reading gave a very accessible account of the matter in "Ungrounded Self-Reference: The solution to the Liar Paradox?", which you can find here: https://digitalworks.union.edu/ephemeris/vol13/iss1/4/.

So are you just agreeing with me on the "This statement is false" being complete nonsense.

Yes, but I just want to clarify the phrase "complete nonsense": The Liar has no semantic truth value aka. it is "meaningless". It is not nonsense in terms of syntax, i.e. it is a grammatical sentence. Not that you would disagree, and in everyday language I might describe The Liar as "complete nonsense", but I try to be very clear when posting here (I've been eaten alive before!).

@HelpMePlease: If you want to understand this stuff, you must learn logic. There is no way around this. Thinking that the so-called "liar paradox" is actually meaningful and worth thinking about is exactly the same as thinking "Let x be an integer such that x = x+1." is meaningful and worth thinking about. Both are equally nonsense.

The liar paradox is not nonsense. We understand what it says. The problem is that while the liar sentence appears to state a proposition, it is problematic to assign a truth value to it.
It is worth noting that we cannot avoid the problem by supposing that a sentence may be true, false or nonsensical. We could just reintroduce the paradox with, "This sentence is either false or nonsense". Also, we can construct combinations of sentences, such that no one of them is self-referential, but the combination of all of them is paradoxical to evaluate.
Students of logic and language are interested in paradoxes such as this because they can tell us interesting things about how logic and language work. An analogy is that neuroscientists who study human vision often investigate optical illusions because those can provide information about how our brains process visual data.
There is an enormous literature on the liar paradox, and many ways of handling it. A common approach is to hold that for some reason or other the liar sentence fails to be a proposition with a truth value. Some claim that the sentence is false, or that it is both true and false. Others have supposed that it tells us something about the relation between the truth of a proposition and some state of affairs that grounds it. Others that it tells us something about the concept of truth: maybe it is not always the case that "P is true" if and only if P. Others maintain that it tells us something about the limitations of natural languages: that they are unable to avoid inconsistency when making statements about truth.
Examining these options is valuable to the logician because they help to bring these questions to the surface. There is a good introduction to the paradox in the SEP article.

I am familiar with the paradox.
It just makes no more sense than saying "The elephant is false". See this article : https://steve-patterson.com/resolving-the-liars-paradox/ for a good explanation of what I mean. Its like when you say "the sentence is false" you wonder what is false? Is it the the phrase "the sentence"? That makes no sense. Is it referring to the whole sentence so that its "The sentence "the sentence is false" is false"? Theres an infinite recursion. I believe the sentence is false is just as nonsensical as the sentence is true.

There are many everyday contexts where we do want to use "... is false" and "... is true" and seem to be able to use those predicates in a meaningful way. For instance, someone may say "Einstein's theory of general relativity is true, according to me, but ..." Or "Yes, what you just said is true. So, let's ..." If we can refer to other sentences (or what someone said in an assertion) as true or false, then at frist blush we should also be able to let a sentence refer back to itself. "This sentence is written in English" - meaningful, and true, though not informative to English speakers.

The problem with the Liar is not that there is an infinite regress. It's simply that if it is true then it is false, and if it is false then it is true. it refers to the sentence "itself", that is, to "what that sentence is saying/asserting", to "the posited fact" - as @Bumble says, however you want to construe it, as long as you use "truth" (rather than for instance "...is provable", "... can be based on evidence"), the paradox will reappear. A similar paradox is G. E. Moore's "It's raining, but I don't believe it." This is also incoherent, but somehow not as strict as the Liar :)

In other words, if you want to consider "This sentence is true" as "nonsense", that's perfectly fine. No one will object, except at some street party perhaps if you chit-chat about logic. You have to ask "So what if it's nonsense or not? Who cares?" In math or logic people do care, since they wonder what can be meaninfully expressed (in a formal language for instance) and how can we prevent errors, which kind of arguments should we be suspicious of (and why).

Btw - I have to correct myself. You can see it as (or construe it as) an infinite regress. (To establish that it's true, we have to establish that what it says is the case. What it says is that it's false. To establish that we have to establish that that it is false is true. Etc etc.)  (It's just that the usual way of presenting the contradiction can be seen as short-circuiting that regress. The short-circuiting is valid if the self-reference is deemed possible/meaningful.)

"This sentence is nonsense" might in fact be a true statement. Then what would we do?

I mean what does the statment "this statement is false" even mean? You might as well just claim "this statement is green" or "this statement is purple" to have meaning as well.

Part 1 : There is only one variation where liars paradox can have meaning.
Say you know a person named Alice. Say you know that everything that Alice has said before the present moment has been a lie (100% of statements she said were lies). Now lets say that Alice states "Everything I say is a lie" and then dies (not being able to say anything else for the rest of her life). Now that would be a paradox. On one hand, since 100% of statements Alice stated before her last statement were lies, then "Everything I said in my life is a lie" is a true statement.

Part 2 : However, if thats a true statement, then everything Alice says is not a lie, so she lied when she claimed "everything I say is a lie". This is a genuine paradox. If she had stated "Everything I said in my life is true", this statement would be just as false as the other statements she stated earlier on. "This statement is false" sounds as bullshit as "This statement is true" as it doesnt really seem to have the property of truth/false. Its no different than saying "This statement is colorless" or "This statement is green".

@HelpMePlease how about this: I have two propositions: 1. The sky is green 2. Proposition 1 is false. - are these two sensible propositions, which contain information and are not "nonsensical" ? - I think so. Now if we replace the first proposition with 1. Proposition 2 is true - Does this make Proposition 2 suddenly nonsensical? Proposition 2 is the same unchanged proposition. And if it was sensible before, the context around it should not change that.

@HelpMePlease I mean, I do claim that "this statement is green" or "this statement is purple" have meaning; they're both false. But the same words printed in green text or in purple text respectively would be true statements. For another example, I'd say "this statement is contained within a pair of quotation marks and is part of a comment left by the user Idran on the Philosophy StackExchange" is clearly true. But if you copied those quoted words unchanged, then the statement in your comment would be false. And if I changed my username, the statement would become false.

Fine, what about "this elephant is false". Is that a meaningless statement @Idran

@HelpMePlease Yes, because elephants don't have truth values. But statements do have truth values. I'd say that in general, anything of the form "this X is Y" has meaning when Y is a member of a category that is possessed by X, and is meaningless otherwise. That's not quite comparable, though, because "this" isn't being used in the same context in that example; it's specifically being used in a self-referential context in the liar's paradox. Unless "this elephant is false" is being spoken by an elephant, at least, in which case it is comparable.

@Idran Okay then what is the meaning of "this statement is true." What even is its truth-value (though thats irrelevant to the general question). Its like saying "What I am claiming is true" but you aren't really claiming anything. Idk if my confusion makes sense to you


Why isn't the Liar's Paradox just accepted to be complete nonsense?

Other answers here are giving a narrow definition of "nonsense".  But yes it is.   Or at least not true/false.
A statement "Please buy milk at the store." is not true/false.  "This statement is true" is even more so.
My understanding is:
A true/false statement must either match/conflict with fact or be provable/disprovable from given axioms.
I don't see how the phrase "this statement" is sufficiently specific to ever be true or false.

Well what about this statement then?

I agree with this statement but I am more so curious on why people don't accept this take. Saying "this statement is true" is like saying "this statement is green" or "this statement is purple".

"Please buy milk at the store." isnt a statement though, as far as I understand how the term is being used here.  It's a request, which is a type of sentence that isnt expected to have a truth value.

@JMac I agree!  My point exactly.  Many "not nonsense" strings of words are not proper "Statements" and thus neither True or False.  So why all the fuss over finding one... i.e. "this statement is false".

The concise way I've heard it is to simply ask the question:

"What part of 'This sentence is false' don't you understand?"

To a lot of people, this comes across as a defensive dismissal.  But, to a philosopher, this is a prompt to start a reflective investigation! There are four words in the bit in single quotation marks, and each of them suggests a slightly different track to start going down:

"Sentence".  What is the substance of language?  Is a sentence a particular individual utterance in time, a composition of words, of concepts, of sound waves, of meanings, of a logical or mathematical relationship of things to ideas?
"This".  What is reference? How do we connect to things in the world, how is it that humans apprehend, form ideas about what we perceive, and come to relate what we say to those things in everyday speech?  Can sentences or abstract things like meanings and concepts be the subjects of reference, and if so, how does that even work?
"Is".  What is the logical structure between things and their properties?  How do you identify and distinguish individuals, determine that certain features apply or do not apply to individuals.  Are there individuals, are there properties, is there any "thing" at all?
"False".  What does it mean for a speech act to correctly or incorrectly connect to the things in the world?  If a person speaks falsely, is this just a nonsense statement?  Is it possible to speak falsely, or counterfactually, but still be referring to things that have an underlying truth to them? How can we tell the difference, if at all, or use that difference strategically in our actions?

It is by no means clear that this entire realm of philosophical consideration is ultimately nonsensical, but neither does that mean that we should presume that everything is fine and well, because yes, this does give us some really bizarre conclusions about the possibility of relating truth to assertion.  In fact, each element seems, on the face of it, to talk about something really quite primal in our shared, linguistic experience of the world, but if we can't clip them together in this way, what does that say about our system of language as a whole, and is there anything we can do about that?

This is a truly beautiful philosophical answer - leading back to the questions behind the initial question.

The Liar Paradox, as many others of its kind, is considered "interesting" or non-nonsensical because it gets people to think long and hard about what is going on.
Naively, i.e. if you tell it to 5-year-old, the receiver will probably not be able to get to any conclusion about how to get out of the conundrum. They will think and think and think and eventually give up with much frustration; or depending on their character, they will just hear it and immediately be uninterested.
On the other spectrum, you end up with one of the deepest results we know about computation from the 20th century, i.e. Gödels incompleteness theorem with has incredibly far-fetching impact on the whole of maths, computer sciences and philosophy of both.
In between these two arguable extremes, such a paradoxon could spawn many other fields within logic, semantics etc. (check out that Wikipedia page for many instances where there have been rather deep explanations of how to resolve the Liar's Paradoxon).
A separate famous example is Achilles and the tortoise - seemingly nonsensical, but it took over 2000 years to figure out, and could only be explained when we invented infinite limits in calculus in the 19th century.
The same can be said for many if not all paradoxons; their worth is in honing our wits, figuring out ways to explain them, end old misconceptions, avoid naive worldviews and so on and forth.

It is nonsense, for some definition of "nonsense", but what can make it interesting is why it is nonsense, what makes it nonsense, how a sentence like that might not be nonsense, how language functions, the nature of self-reference, etc. Analogous problems occur in mathematics, like Russell's paradox, which have motivated new and some would say better formalizations and theories like type theory.

Paradoxes are effectively linguistic anomalies. They are statements that should make sense according to the normal rules and usages of language, but somehow aren't entirely sensible. They're important in the same way that scientific anomalies are: they point out that we don't quite understand something we think we understand, and open the door for advancement.
One can certainly write off the Liar's Paradox as nonsense and it won't affect daily life one whit. By that same token, one can write off other anomalies as nonsense and assert that the earth is a flat, 6000 year old disc; that won't change how one buys groceries or gets to work either. "Who cares?" is a common enough response to things one doesn't understand, but it's not something I recommend as a lifestyle.
